# How to clear all user keystrokes in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yield-return

i'm writing some c# code within Unity game i'm developing.
and there's a problem i can't fix.

i'm using StartCoroutine in my code and inside i'm calling another StartCoroutine. i know that when doing that, there's two threads executing the code in those parts.
but not if i'm calling yield return to that StartCorotuine;

```
IEnumerator StartLoop()
{
    yield return StartCorotuine(GetInputFromUser()); // 1
    // some variables
    yield return StartCorotuine(GetInputFromUser()); // 2
}

IEnumerator GetInputFromUser()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
         print("IN");
    }
    else
    {
         yield return null;
    }

}
```

the problem is, it prints twice.
the buffer isn't empty from the first time calling "GetInputFromUser()" and it keeps it until the second time and enters immediately to the if even when i'm not pressing Space.

things i've tried:

```
Console.Clear();
Console.ReadKey();
Console.ReadLine();
UnityEngine.Rendering.CommandBuffer.Clear();
while(Console.KeyAvailable)
    Console.ReadKey();
```

and some more i can't even remember.

either the whole idea is wrong and somehow it worked till now. or i'm missing something.

any advise? i've googled everything i could think of.

[[[SOLVED]]]
I don't know how it works here, and if you're closing the post or something. but I've solved it.

The problem was, as someone suggested, that the calls happened in the same frame, so i've added another null in between to force skipping to the next frame:

```
IEnumerator StartLoop()
{
    yield return StartCorotuine(GetInputFromUser()); // 1
    // some variables

    yield return null;   // skipping frame


    yield return StartCorotuine(GetInputFromUser()); // 2
}

IEnumerator GetInputFromUser()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
         print("IN");
    }
    else
    {
         yield return null;
    }

}
```

Thanks for the helpers!

Comment: Could you add more context? What exactly is your goal with that? Where is `StartLoop` started?

Comment: yes, the goal is to check if the user presses the SpaceBar more than once. I'm checking if he presses the first time within a time limit and then checks if he presses again. the ```StartLoop``` starts inside ```Start()```

Comment: Coroutibed are not threads. You can skip `StartCoroutine` inside a coroutine and just yield the other method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Coroutines have nothing to do with *threads*! Every Coroutine is executed in the Unity main thread and get their `MoveNext` executed right after `Update` has finished for that behaviour.

---

Your problem should be that in

```
IEnumerator GetInputFromUser()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
         print("IN");
    }
    else
    {
         yield return null;
    }
}
```

in the case there was no input you do `yield return null;` which causes the Coroutine to wait at least **one frame**!

So the second one is executed in the next frame.

**But** in case there was an input you do **not** wait so the next Coroutine is directly started where again you don't wait!

Result: You get your `print` twice without waiting at all.

---

It's not fully clear what you are trying here but I assume you want to wait until `Space` is pressed so you should rather use e.g.

```
bool GetInputFromUser()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
         print("IN");
         return true
    }

    return false;
}
```

And use it like

```
// This now waits until the user presses Space
yield return new WaitUntil (GetInputFromUser);
```

or simply also `yield` for one frame in case there was the input like

```
IEnumerator GetInputFromUser()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
         print("IN");
    }

    yield return null;
}
```

though

> the goal is to check if the user presses the SpaceBar more than once.

It is very very unlikely that a user manages to press the key down twice in two consecutive frames.

---

> `StartLoop` starts inside `Start()`

but at this moment the user can't provide any input yet anyway. So you check only once if the user presses a key within the first frames..

Comment: I've just tried the bool method idea you've suggested, and it failed. it delays all the programs. But maybe it'll work only for the multiple check which I'm trying now

Comment: I've just tried the bool method idea only for the multiple checks, and it still goes right inside the ```if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))```, so it seems to be the buffer problem

Comment: @barelh `GetKeyDown` returns true on the first frame a key is pressed and does not reset until the next frame. There is a cache, because *that's the whole point* of Unity's input manager.

Comment: @barelh I'm assuming when you tried the bool method you had two `WaitUntil()` calls back to back? If you want it to work you'll need to add a `yield return null` between them.

Answer (score 0):

In Start()
I'm waiting for the first Space stroke.
once he has, I'm starting the `StartCorotuine(StartLoop());` sorry for the mixup.

I'm using it like that, maybe it'll be more clear, once the user Starting the loop, I'm waiting for him to press Space. once he has a timer is set on and once the timer has timed the IEnumerator return without Input from the User and I'm getting to the next iteration, the only thing I want to do is to check if the user pressed twice on that Space.

```
{
    while (timer < timeSetInStart)
    {
         If(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
         {    
             print("IN";
             yield break;
         }
         else
         {
             yield return null;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a specific reason why this needs to be in a coroutine but it might be easier to handle this all in `Update()`:

```
bool spacePressed = false;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (spacePressed)
        {
            print("Space pressed twice");
            spacePressed = false;
        }
        else
        {
            print("Space pressed once");
            spacePressed = true;
        }
    }
}
```